# Sequelize - How to Insert data, and then update

Tags: node.js, orm, mariadb, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequalize ORM for node.js/maria db project.

What I'm trying to do is, generate new table for product data using raw query.

The sequence of my logic is written below.

Step 1. Destroy table to reset data.

Step 2. Insert product data.

Step 3. Update price data in product data.

Step 4. Update stock data in product data.

The problem is step 3, and 4. It is not working!
What I found is... 'Insert' took some time to finish. So, 'Update' could not fulfilled, because there's no product data yet.

Is there any idea to invoke step 3~4, soon after step 2 is finished?

Thanks in advance.

```
const generateProductList = () => {

    return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {

        try {

            await ProductPresentation.destroy({ truncate: true })

            const productSql = `INSERT INTO m_product_presentation (productId, sku, name, status, urlKey, category, shortDescription, imageSmall, imageThumbnail) 
            SELECT id, sku, name, status, urlKey, category, shortDescription, imageSmall, imageThumbnail FROM m_product;`

            const priceSql = `UPDATE m_product_presentation INNER JOIN m_price
            ON m_product_presentation.productId = m_price.productId
            SET m_product_presentation.priceRrp = m_price.priceRrp, m_product_presentation.priceRegular = m_price.priceRegular, m_product_presentation.priceSpecial = m_price.priceSpecial;`

            const stockSql = `UPDATE m_product_presentation INNER JOIN m_inventory
            ON m_product_presentation.productId = m_inventory.productId
            SET m_product_presentation.stockAvailability = m_inventory.stockAvailability, m_product_presentation.stockQty = m_inventory.stockQty;`


            // What I want is, Create initial data first. And then, update price and stock info. But, It fail...
            await ProductPresentation.sequelize.query(productSql, { type: QueryTypes.INSERT })
            await ProductPresentation.sequelize.query(priceSql, { type: QueryTypes.UPDATE })
            await ProductPresentation.sequelize.query(stockSql, { type: QueryTypes.UPDATE })

            resolve()

        } catch(err) {

            reject(err)
            logger.error(err)

        }

    })
}
```

Comment: Why don't you insert it at a first time with updated stock and update price? Why to run the query related to same product multiple times in the same handler?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is that before updating the values which is dependent on the same product, you can check whether the product is already entered or not.

```js
const generateProductList = () => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      await ProductPresentation.destroy({ truncate: true })
      const productSql = `INSERT INTO m_product_presentation (productId, sku, name, status, urlKey, category, shortDescription, imageSmall, imageThumbnail) 
            SELECT id, sku, name, status, urlKey, category, shortDescription, imageSmall, imageThumbnail FROM m_product;`
      const priceSql = `UPDATE m_product_presentation INNER JOIN m_price
            ON m_product_presentation.productId = m_price.productId
            SET m_product_presentation.priceRrp = m_price.priceRrp, m_product_presentation.priceRegular = m_price.priceRegular, m_product_presentation.priceSpecial = m_price.priceSpecial;`
      const stockSql = `UPDATE m_product_presentation INNER JOIN m_inventory
            ON m_product_presentation.productId = m_inventory.productId
            SET m_product_presentation.stockAvailability = m_inventory.stockAvailability, m_product_presentation.stockQty = m_inventory.stockQty;`

      // Inserting the product in the table
      const product = await ProductPresentation.sequelize.query(productSql, { type: QueryTypes.INSERT })
      // To find if the product is existing the table or not
      const isProductEntered = await sequelize.query(`
      select exists(select 1 from "m_product_presentation" where "productId"=$1)
      `, {
        bind: [`${product[0][0].productId}`],
        type: QueryTypes.SELECT
      });
      if (isProductEntered[0].exists) {
        await ProductPresentation.sequelize.query(priceSql, { type: QueryTypes.UPDATE })
        await ProductPresentation.sequelize.query(stockSql, { type: QueryTypes.UPDATE })
      }
      
      resolve()

    } catch (err) {
      reject(err)
      logger.error(err)
    }
  })
}
```

If the product will be entered only then the update queries will be executed.

Comment: Thanks for your kind guide. But.. I found that root cause was another source code. So I fixed it successfully. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that another source code (Some react code in frontend) cause this issue. I'll close this issue.